# jquery mouseover событие

Tags: jquery

Как отключить триггер у mouseover. Необходимо навести на элемент (изменится класс его), а когда мышку убрать что бы измененный класс остался

Answer (score 2):

Для Вашего случая идеально подойдет функция `mouseenter()`. Она срабатывает когда пользователь наводит курсор на элемент (не вызывает событие когда курсор выходит из поля объекта). Подробнее Вы можете прочитать в официальной документации jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Пример действия (взято с сайта jQuery):

```js
var i = 0;
$("div.overout")
  .mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse over x " + i);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
  });

var n = 0;
$("div.enterleave")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    n += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse enter x " + n);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse leave");
  });
```

```css
div.out {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: #d6edfc;
  float: left;
}

div.in {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #fc0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>mouseover demo</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="out overout">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="out enterleave">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```